# Highlight a form select element if its value is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form where people sign up for a shift. There are multiple shifts on the page, and I have an `onchange` event that sends the sign-up via Ajax.

```
<select name="user" class="assign_user" id="user1">
   <option value="user1234" selected="selected">Joe Bloggs</option>
   <option value="">No-one</option>
   <option value="user1235">Jane Mahon</option>
   <option value="user1236">Ahmed Kitab</option>
   <option value="user1237">Dave Smew</option>
</select>
```

If  `<option value="">No-one</option>` is selected, I want to highlight the `select` element in yellow.

I cannot think of a way to do this with just CSS. I tried

```
select[value=''] {  
   background-color:lightyellow; 
}
```

but the attribute filter in the square brackets doesn't accept empty values, as far as I know.

**EDIT**: just to be clear, empty select elements should be highlighted when the page loads, as well as when the element changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.empty {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function userChanged(select) {
    select = $(select);
    if (select.val() === "") select.addClass("empty");
    else select.removeClass("empty");
}

// UPDATED: Initialization
$(function() {
    var user1 = $("#user1");
    user1.change(function() { userChanged(user1); });

    // Highlights select when page loads.
    userChanged(user1);
});
```

**UPDATE:** Future solution uses **CSS** only. From: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

```
select:has(option:checked[value='']) {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Comment: pretty similar to my solution (except mine has an event listener in the jQuery instead of in the HTML). Your JavaScript doesn't take into account the need to flag the elements as empty when the page loads, either.

Comment: You are right. Added the initialization function and a CSS selector **not yet** implemented by browsers.

Comment: gave your solution a vote because it now does the necessary but I have still accepted my own answer because it uses the same CSS classes as my HTML, and because there is no need to add an onchange attribute in the HTML in my solution, so I think it's still better.

Comment: The `onchange` is not needed in the HTML because of `user1.change(function() { userChanged(user1); });`. Maybe I should have  added a comment, but it is ok. Thank you for the vote! Extra note: the attribute filter does accept empty values. It didn't work for your select because the value is in the `option` child, not the element itself.

Comment: good to know that the attribute filter does accept empty values (and makes sense that select wouldn't because it is the option that is selected and not the select element), thanks.

Comment: I made this the accepted answer because of your update to the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.assign_user').on('change', function() {
          var user_number = $(this).val();
          var shiftid = $(this).siblings('input[name=shiftid]').val();

          /*send data to database via Ajax*/
          $.ajax({
            url: "/admin/saveshift",
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'action': 'update', 'shiftid': shiftid, 'user_number': user_number },
            success: function()
                  {
                    console.log("added a shift ");
                    /* message to user to say the record is updated */
                    $('#assigned').html('Updated');
                    $('#assigned').show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#assigned').fadeOut();
                        return false;
                    }, 10000);
                  }
          });
          /* if null is selected, add class unassigned */
          if ($(this).val() == '') {
              $(this).addClass('unassigned');
          } else {
              $(this).removeClass('unassigned');
          }

        });
        /* when page loads, if null is selected, add class unassigned */
        $('.assign_user').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).addClass('unassigned');
            }
        });
});
```

**CSS**

```
select.unassigned {
    background-color:lightyellow;
}
```

I couldn't think of a way to do this with just CSS, hence the jQuery.